# Was LM1 of Apollo 5 equipped with additional sensors and telemetry for the umanned "fire in the hole" test?

Tags: apollo-program, testing, lunar-module

The first unmanned test of the Lunar Module was done in mission Apollo 5 LM 1. The separation of the ascent stage from the descent stage was done during flight. Did they install additional sensors and telemetry channels to supervize the separation? 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional instrumentation known as Development Flight Instrumentation (DFI) was present.

The [Apollo Experience Report - Development Flight Instrumentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740010398.pdf) (p. 38)- states

> A total of 195 DFI measurements was installed on the LM-1 vehicle for
>   the Apollo 5 mission. The flight equipment used is listed in table
>   C-11. The instrumentation system performed satisfactorily, with the
>   exception of seven measurements that did not respond as planned.
>   Four thermocouple measurements malfunctioned  (probably became
>   unbonded), and three low-pressure measurements failed (probably
>   because of constricted ports from engine firing).

Unfortunately the referenced table lists the components used by the DFI system, but does not list the parameters that were monitored.

Page 48 of the [Post-Flight Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700024869.pdf) discusses the sensors that failed.

Comment: Oooh, that is an obscure AER.  Nice find!

Comment: @DrSheldon I also found one on the "iron pilot" for that mission, the Lunar Module Mission Programmer, that may be of interest: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750013238.pdf

Comment: 90 strain gages, 45 pressure transducers, 18 vibration systems, 36 resistance thermometers, 25 thermocouples and 2 strain/temperature systems, that is not a small DFI system!

Comment: @Uwe I would love to find a list showing specifically what was monitored, but I haven't been able to.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I just found this [paper](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/UAH-19671016-ApolloSaturenConsolidatedInstrumentationPlanForAS204LM1.pdf), looks very good!

Comment: @Uwe I looked at that. It's a great document but it only covers the launch vehicle IIRC. I used it in this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41481/6944

Comment: These documents might have some information about DFI:

Apollo 5 First Lunar Module Test in Space, NASA Press Release 68-6, January 11, 1968

Apollo 5 Mission Report, MSC-PA-R-68-7, NASA Manned Space Center, March 1968

Final Flight Evaluation Report: Apollo 5 Mission, D2-117017-2 Rev C, NASA Office of Manned Space Flight, October 1968